# Displaying divs as list items in a horizontally scrolling parent div

Tags: html, css, list

I am creating a list application, and I am having trouble displaying the list items. I would like the items to be inline with eachother, and if they overflow from the parent div, they simply continue flowing and are hidden from view until scrolled to.

The issue that I am having is that the items go to a new line instead of continuing in the x direction. What could I do to prevent this and have them inline with each other and have the parent div, scroll upon overflow?

Here is an image showing my issue and what I wish to result in:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hy46X.png

All help will be greatly appreciated.

```css
.container {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    height: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="item">
        <p class="itemContent">Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p class="itemContent">Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p class="itemContent">Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p class="itemContent">Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p class="itemContent">Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p class="itemContent">Text</p>
    </div>
    <div class="item">
        <p class="itemContent">Text</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Can you share your code?

Comment: Here is a jsFiddle of my issue:

http://jsfiddle.net/ts7x9es8/

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The combination of `white-space: nowrap` and `overflow-x: scroll` (or `auto`) will do the trick.

```css
.container {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 255, 0.2);
    position: absolute;
    left: 10px;
    top: 10px;
    width: calc(100% - 200px);
    height: auto;
    overflow-x: auto;
    white-space: nowrap;
}

.item {
    background-color: rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.2);
    display: inline-block;
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
    
    <div class="item"><p class="itemContent">Text</p></div>
    <div class="item"><p class="itemContent">Text</p></div>
    <div class="item"><p class="itemContent">Text</p></div>
    <div class="item"><p class="itemContent">Text</p></div>
    <div class="item"><p class="itemContent">Text</p></div>
    <div class="item"><p class="itemContent">Text</p></div>
    <div class="item"><p class="itemContent">Text</p></div>
    <div class="item"><p class="itemContent">Text</p></div>
    <div class="item"><p class="itemContent">Text</p></div>
    <div class="item"><p class="itemContent">Text</p></div>
    <div class="item"><p class="itemContent">Text</p></div>
    <div class="item"><p class="itemContent">Text</p></div>
    <div class="item"><p class="itemContent">Text</p></div>

</div>
```

Also see [your fixed fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ts7x9es8/1/)